# C# ParseExact not picking the format

Tags: c#, datetime, ssis

I Need help with this simple and silly thing ..
Want to be able to convert this string representation `"Oct 9 2017 2:45:67:145PM"` to date.
I am using code below:

```
string strDate = "Oct 9 2017 2:45:67:145PM";
DateTime dtTroubleDate;
dtTroubleDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate.ToString(), "MMM d yyyy h:mm:ss:ffftt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
MessageBox.Show("dtTroubleDate String : " + dtTroubleDate.ToString());
```

This is a C# code within a SSIS package. I am reading the date from a file. 
Need to store in the database as 'datetime2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never in the history of the Gregorian calendar have been a time with 67 seconds...
This must be a typo in the file itself. The format you are using is OK, but I would recommend using `TryParseExact` instead of `ParseExact` for this very reason.

When using `ParseExact` you are basically saying "I know the string representation of the datetime value will always be in this specific format and I will always be able to parse it.

However, that is rarely the case - as most of the time string representation of datetime values are written by fallible humans, occasionally there will be typos - and that's exactly what the `TryParse` methods are all about.

```
string strDate = "Oct 9 2017 2:45:67:145PM";
DateTime dtTroubleDate;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(
    strDate, 
    "MMM d yyyy h:mm:ss:ffftt", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out dtTroubleDate))           
{
    // Datetime is valid
}
```

Comment: you won me at `Never in the history of the Gregorian calendar have been a time with 67 seconds.` until today :) up-vote just for that

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks! Though I think the rest of my answer is the more important part, I do appreciate your appreciation of my humor :-)

Comment: Thanks, Zohar :) nice one. I actually did pick it up soon after i posted the question. I actually deleted the question. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @rRana Good to know the problem is solved. Please either accept the answer so that other people will know the problem is solved, or delete the question. Thanks!